# how to decode JSON to get value of variable

Tags: php, json

JSON URL: https://www.mylivepolls.com/api.php
I am trying to decode this json but getting error. What am i doing wrong here? 
Any help will be appreciated.

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.mylivepolls.com/api.php");
$data = json_decode($json);
$var = $data->mchdata->match[0]->id;
echo $var;
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: @pascalzoet This is the error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in.

Comment: It's working for me. Does your file_get_contents() work?

Comment: It's working for me aswell. Your server does not allow file_get_contents() probably.

Comment: Dump `$json` from the `file_get_contents` call.

Comment: works for me, some servers do not allow the use of file_get_contents for security reasons

Comment: thanks guys this works on another server!! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try this or you can use `curl` instead of `file_get_contents` using cookie jar.

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.mylivepolls.com/api.php");
$data = json_decode($json, true);

if(is_array($data) && isset($data['mchdata']) && isset($data['mchdata']['match'])) {
    $matches = $data['mchdata']['match'];

    if(is_array($matches)) {
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            $id = $match['id'];
        }
    }
    $current_match = current($matches);
    echo $var = $current_match['id'];
}
```

Using Curl:

```
$ckfile = tempnam (sys_get_temp_dir(), 'apicookiename');

$handle = curl_init("https://www.mylivepolls.com/api.php");

curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

$json = curl_exec($handle); 
$data = json_decode($json, true);

if(is_array($data) && isset($data['mchdata']) && isset($data['mchdata']['match'])) {
    $matches = $data['mchdata']['match'];

    if(is_array($matches)) {
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            $id = $match['id'];
        }
    }
    $current_match = current($matches);
    echo $var = $current_match['id'];
}
```

Thanks